# Nodejs: request ends with incomplete data

Tags: node.js, request

So I have an rss feed url, that has around 200 items. However, request module is only able to fetch at random 15 - 20 items, and it ends in the middle of receiving the response without giving any error.

I tried with regular curl, and I am receiving all the data, any reason for this descrepancy?

```
const { request } = require('https');

const url = //some url;

const req = request(url, (res) => {
  console.log(res.statusCode)
  let data = "";
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    data += d;
  })
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('data ---', data);
  })
})

req.end();
```

I tried with request npm package, and it's still the same